# MqttNet - How to implement MQTT server (broker) to receive messages that were published by MQTT client

Tags: c#, asp.net, mqtt, mqttnet

I want to get sensor data that are published by a mqtt client. The client connect to my server but I cannot found any event on MqttServer that handle published messages by the client. Is it possible or is there any example about it ?

P.S: In the old versions Mqttnet server has UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler that handle incoming messages.

Find an example or solution about subscribing in a server (broker).

Comment: As a rule you do not write a MQTT broker to do this, you implement another client that connects to the broker and subscribes to the messages the sensor is publishing

Comment: Oh, I see. thank for your comment. Do you recommend make a BackgroundService as client in my asp host?

Comment: Or take a look at this sample. This replaces the previous `ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler` https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Samples/Server/Server_Intercepting_Samples.cs